# Detect any (entire) row selection in entire sheet and unprotect?

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for the following code:

sheet is currently locked (enabled for locked cell selection).

VBA detects if any whole row(s) say 21, 22 are selected and automatically unprotects sheet.

THEN:

if these exact rows are deleted.. sheet automatically protects again.

If the user deselects these rows.. sheet protects again.

(this is design to perform specific row deletion)

very crudely:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    IF Rows("1:1").Select AND/OR Rows("2:2").Select AND/OR Rows("3:3").Select then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    End If

    ActiveCell.Row.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: Something like this??       Sub team()

If Selection.Address(0, 0) = "1:1" Then
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Remember to set `Application.enableEvents = True` first

**EDIT** Changed Code as OP's new spec in discussion

Restriction: The ENTIRE row ( every cell must be unlocked in order to be able to select the whole row)

```
' remember the event's name is `Worksheet_SelectionChange`
' NOT Worksheet1_SelectionChange
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ' the rows to be selected
    Dim row1 As Range
    Dim row2 As Range
    Dim row3 As Range
    Dim mergedRange As Range
    Set row1 = Me.Rows("1:1")
    Set row2 = Me.Rows("3:3")
    Set row3 = Me.Rows("5:5")
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim Match As Boolean
    Set mergedRange = Application.Union(row1, row2)
    Set mergedRange = Application.Union(mergedRange, row3)
    Match = False


    ' check if it selects only 1 row
    If Target.Areas.Count <> 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Protect
        Exit Sub
    End If


    ' check if it's select the first 500 rows
    If Target.Areas.Item(1).Row > 0 And Target.Areas.Item(1).Row <= 500 Then
        'check if it's selecting the WHOLE row
        If Me.Rows(Target.Areas.Item(1).Row & ":" & Target.Areas.Item(1).Row).Areas.Item(1).Count = Target.Areas.Item(1).Count Then
            ' check if the "B" Column of this row's backgound color is blue
            If Me.Cells(Target.Areas.Item(1).Row, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(197, 217, 241) Then
                Match = True
            End If
        End If
    End If


    If Match Then

        'MsgBox "ActiveSheet.Unprotect"
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Else
        Debug.Print "notMatch"
        'ActiveCell.Row.Delete
       ActiveSheet.Protect
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Larry! Unfortunately I'm getting the "ambiguous name detected Worksheet_SelectionChange" error whenever I select a cell. Also where do I put that line of code: Application.enableevents=true?

Comment: You need to replace your original `Worksheet_SelectionChange` Sub with my. (You should backup your original sub by changing the sub name a bit ) . You can type it in the immediate window in VBE (CTRL + G) and type ENTER

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet1_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = True           I have placed it after the modified sub name. (i realised I have another macro with the same sub name) but nothing is happening now!

Comment: do not place `Application.EnableEvents = True` inside the sub
you can put it in a new `sub` , `F5` to enable it.

Also, to test my function, you need to select row 1,3,5 using `CTRL`

Comment: OK, I have placed application enable events in ThisWorkbook to activate when the sheet opens: events are enabled. I have selected those rows 1,3,5 but still nothing happening

Comment: so you have put `Application.enableEvents = true` inside `ThisWorkbook` Module 's `Workbook_open` Event and re-open the excel? And you need to select the whole row 1,3,5 only. NOT 1-5. You can also change my code's ` Debug.Print "notMatch"` to `MsgBox "not match"` to see if the code is working. Also, which sheet's module have you placed `Worksheet_SelectionChange` under? It only works for THAT particular sheet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23704/discussion-between-larry-and-user1717622)

Comment: 'Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 
Application.EnableEvents = True         this was placed inside ThisWorkbook, and the sheet was reopened.         I placed your code within the module for that the sheet I am using that property. I also selected just your rows. maybe I can post a link?

End Sub

Comment: @user1717622 i'm looking into the issue, see chatroom for update

Comment: it's Worksheet_SelectionChange
instead of Worksheet1_SelectionChange

Comment: Yes, this is working now! I see that the functionality it is performing is (with a slight modification by me): if those three rows are selected the sheet now unprotects and displays message box.  this is almost there! and to simplify things I will remove the requirement to be able to select multiple rows:  basically: how do we modify this code such that if any single row from 1-500 is selected the sheet unprotects and then (as in the original spec) if the next action is delete the selected row or (deselect) the sheet protects again? this will bve a really nifty bit of code once it works!

Comment: the next action  ( deselect) <--- can you explain further? and what are you trying to achieve? Like a "Screen lock" on smart phone? And I don't think we can detect "delete" row event..

Comment: shall we move to chat? I'll respond there